# How to view the .cod file generated by VC++ compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, assembly

In Visual Studio there is a way to output the compilation result in the form of both source code, assembler code and the machine code by setting the compiler output properties:
[image: compiler options]
The generated file has the .cod extension which is by default associated with Visual Studio. However, on opening the file it is just opened as a plain text file, no syntax highlighting etc. is available here:
[image: screenshot of cod file in visual studio]

Is there any tool that would allow me to visualize these files, at least to be able to separate the comments containing the source code, addresses and the assembly code optically?

**EDIT:** I tried NotePad++, my preferred editor, as the very firs solution and it is already quite good how I can visualize it there using Assembler as a language, but still there are problems with hexadecimal numbers, the assembly code is not aligned properly etc... 
[image: NotePad++]

Comment: Actually COD is not an assembly but object dump.

Comment: This is true, but I don't have any highlighting scheme for "object dump" and it still contains assembler instructions in plaintext form.

Comment: Obvious question, why do you want to do so?

Comment: @alexander - If you set the tab stops propely (8 characters) it will line up in nice fixed columns. Assembly language really never had syntax coloring, but fixed positions for each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Notepad ++.
and don;t forget to select the Language by clicking Language->A->Assembly

You will get the necessary syntax highlighting

Comment: This is the first thing I did, but I has some problems with colorizing the machine code and addresses: some hexadecimal numbers are not resolved there. But thanks for your suggestion!